# Construct chain of links from list

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have a list of key/value pairs and I need to detect chains in the list where the value matches a key.

E.g. from the below there could be 12, 23, 34 or 62, 23, 34

```
Key  Value
1    2
3    4
2    3
6    2
```

More than one value can be pointing to the same key but I need to store different 'chains' for each unique start and end point. The list could be in any order.

I'm using Java but am I bit stuck on how to tackle this problem.

Please help!

Comment: I think you meant "12, 23, 34 or 62, 23, 34" instead.

Comment: yeh, my mistake, just corrected it - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion!

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Chain
{
    private static Map< String , String > map;

    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        map = new HashMap< String , String >();

        map.put( "1" , "2" );
        map.put( "3" , "4" );
        map.put( "2" , "3" );
        map.put( "6" , "2" );

        for ( String key : map.keySet() )
        {
            System.out.print( "(" + key + "," + map.get( key ) + ")" );
            recurse( map.get( key ) );
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static void recurse( String value )
    {
        if ( map.containsKey( value ) )
        {
            System.out.print( " (" + value + "," + map.get( value ) + ")" );
            recurse( map.get( value ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Gives you the following output:

```
(3,4)
(2,3) (3,4)
(1,2) (2,3) (3,4)
(6,2) (2,3) (3,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`, store all your pairs in that map, and then iterate the map.

Pseudo-code:

```
// 1st step
foreach(key, value){
    if(!map.containsKey(key)){
        map.put(key, new ArrayList());
    }
    map.get(key).add(value);
}
// 2nd step
foreach(entry /* of map */){
    if(map.containsKey(entry.value)){
       // print pairs
    }
}
```

Obviously this is pseudo-code that won't compile but it should get you started

Answer (score 0):

Since this looks like homework, I will give you hints to help you solve the problem yourself, rather than giving you a full solution.

1. For any key in the map, you can get the corresponding value by calling `Map.get(key)`.
2. You can use any value as a key to get its corresponding value (if there is one).
3. You can iterate through all keys in the map using `Map.getKeys()`.

If you only want to print out the chains, this should suffice. If you want to store the chains in some different data structure, please give more information.