# java 8 functional style of chaining links

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I have a `Map<String , String>` which indicates links from A to B. I want to chain all possible routes. for example :

```
[A , B]
[B , C]
[C , D]
[E , F]
[F , G]
[H , I]
```

will output

```
[A , B , C , D]
[E , F , G]
[H , I]
```

I found similar question here (but not fully fulfills my requirement) : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10176274/298430

And here is my solution :

```
public static <T> Set<List<T>> chainLinks(Map<T , T> map) {
    Set<List<T>> resultSet = new HashSet<>();

    map.forEach((from, to) -> {
      if (!map.containsValue(from)) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(from);
        list.addAll(inner(to, map));
        resultSet.add(list);
      }
    });
    return resultSet;
  }

  private static <T> List<T> inner(T from , Map<T , T> map) {
    if (map.containsKey(from)) {
      List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
      list.add(from);
      list.addAll(inner(map.get(from), map));
      return list;
    } else {
      List<T> end = new ArrayList<>();
      end.add(from);
      return end;
    }
  }
```

and the test case :

```
  @Test
  public void testChainLinks()  {
    Map<String , String> map = new HashMap<String , String>() {{
      put("A" , "B");
      put("B" , "C");
      put("C" , "D");
      put("E" , "F");
      put("F" , "G");
      put("H" , "I");
    }};

    Utils.chainLinks(map).forEach(list -> {
      logger.info("list = {}" , list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" -> ")));
    });
  }
```

It does work correctly :

```
list = H -> I
list = E -> F -> G
list = A -> B -> C -> D
```

But I don't like my solution. Because I feel it can be solved in a more functional-style . I can feel the smell of `stream.fold()` here . I tried but in vain to convert my code to a pure functional style : which means no intermediate objects creation...

Is it possible ? Any hints are grateful !

Comment: Sorry , typo . I mean Stream.reduce().

Comment: Hopefully your inputs don't have cycles like `put("A", "B"); put("B", "A");`. Otherwise the supplied solutions will not work.

Comment: Yes , I am sure there will be no cyclic links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an alternative solution using the custom collector with close to linear complexity. It's really faster than the solutions proposed before, though looks somewhat uglier.

```
public static <T> Collector<Entry<T, T>, ?, List<List<T>>> chaining() {
    BiConsumer<Map<T, ArrayDeque<T>>, Entry<T, T>> accumulator = (
            m, entry) -> {
        ArrayDeque<T> k = m.remove(entry.getKey());
        ArrayDeque<T> v = m.remove(entry.getValue());
        if (k == null && v == null) {
            // new pair does not connect to existing chains
            // create a new chain with two elements
            k = new ArrayDeque<>();
            k.addLast(entry.getKey());
            k.addLast(entry.getValue());
            m.put(entry.getKey(), k);
            m.put(entry.getValue(), k);
        } else if (k == null) {
            // new pair prepends an existing chain
            v.addFirst(entry.getKey());
            m.put(entry.getKey(), v);
        } else if (v == null) {
            // new pair appends an existing chain
            k.addLast(entry.getValue());
            m.put(entry.getValue(), k);
        } else {
            // new pair connects two existing chains together
            // reuse the first chain and update the tail marker
            // btw if k == v here, then we found a cycle
            k.addAll(v);
            m.put(k.getLast(), k);
        }
    };
    BinaryOperator<Map<T, ArrayDeque<T>>> combiner = (m1, m2) -> {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    };
    // our map contains every chain twice: mapped to head and to tail
    // so in finisher we have to leave only half of them 
    // (for example ones connected to the head).
    // The map step can be simplified to Entry::getValue if you fine with
    // List<Collection<T>> result.
    Function<Map<T, ArrayDeque<T>>, List<List<T>>> finisher = m -> m
            .entrySet().stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getValue().getFirst().equals(e.getKey()))
            .map(e -> new ArrayList<>(e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return Collector.of(HashMap::new, accumulator, combiner, finisher);
}
```

Usage:

```
List<List<String>> res = map.entrySet().stream().collect(chaining());
```

(I did not implement the `combiner` step, thus it cannot be used for parallel streams, but it's not very hard to add it as well). The idea is simple: we track partial chains found so far in the map where keys point to chain starts and ends and the values are `ArrayDeque` objects containing the chains found so far. Every new entry updates existing deque (if it appends/prepends it) or merges two deques together.

According to my tests this version works 1000x faster than @saka1029 solution for the 50000 element input array with 100 chains.

Comment: wow , 1000X is awesome . I'll try it later. BTW how do you generate 50000 elements and make sure it doesn't contain cyclic links ?

Comment: @smallufo: something like this: `for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {for(int j=0; j<i*10; j++) {map.put(j*1000+i, (j+1)*1000+i);}}` (for `Map<Integer, Integer>`).

Comment: After do some minor benchmarks . my computer is 15943ms vs 225ms !!! It is very impressive !!! Kudos to @TagirVallev .  (I need some time to digest your algorithm ).

Comment: @smallufo, I added some comments to the code. Hopefully it's helpful.

Answer (score 6):

Non-recursive solution:

```
    Set<List<String>> result = map.keySet().stream()
        .filter(k -> !map.containsValue(k))
        .map(e -> new ArrayList<String>() {{
            String x = e;
            add(x);
            while (map.containsKey(x))
                add(x = map.get(x));
        }})
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Thanks. your solution is simpler. ( But there are still intermediate objects created )

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: included filter from  David Pérez Cabrera's comment to remove intermediate lists.

Well you can easily recursion:

```
private static Set<List<String>> chainLinks(Map<String, String> map) {
    return map.keySet().stream().filter(k -> !map.containsValue(k)).map(  (key) ->
                 calc(key, map, new LinkedList<>())

    ).collect(Collectors.toSet());

}
private static List<String> calc(String key,Map<String, String> map,List<String> list){
    list.add(key);
    if (map.containsKey(key))
        return calc(map.get(key),map,list);
    else
        return list;
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the filter: return map.keySet().stream()
                .filter(k -> !map.containsValue(k))
                .map((key)
                -> calc(key, map, new LinkedList<>())
        ).collect(Collectors.toSet());

Comment: Well , you code doesnt not filter out intermediate node as starting node. The starting node should not be any linked node. ( in my example , your algorithm shows "C ->D" , which should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks @DavidPérezCabrera . it Works. But , is there any non-recursive solution ? (for example : stream.fold )

Comment: I thought with reduce functions, but the algorithm was O (n^2). In fact, I couldnt improve yours (at recursive part) I prefer to invert map 》invMap to avoid containsValue invocation